Angular Material Button Color Not Applying with routerLinkActive
I'm using Angular Material for my application and have the following button setup:
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>
    <a routerLink="/">My Messages</a>
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/create" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">
        New Post
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-toolbar>


Issue:
When I navigate to the /create route, I expect the New Post button to have the accent color defined by mat-accent when active. However, the text color remains black instead of the expected pink from the indigo-pink theme.
I've confirmed that the theme is properly imported in angular.json:
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
]



In the above image, you can see the

.mat-mdc-button.mat-accent{ 
    --mdc-text-button-label-text-color : #ff4081
}

is overridden by
.mat-toolbar .mat-mdc-button-base.mat-mdc-button-base.mat-unthemed{
   --mdc-text-button-label-text-color : var(--mat-toolbar-container-text-color)
}

What I've Tried:

Clearing the Angular cache.


Inspecting CSS to check for specificity issues.


Ensuring all dependencies are up to date.

Why is the mat-accent color not applying to the button when active?
How can I override the toolbar's styling to allow the accent color to show properly?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

what version of angular and angular material are you using, could you replicate the issue on angular material stackblitz examples and update on the question, need working example for debugging.

The reason is that the
.mat-mdc-button.mat-accent{ 
    --mdc-text-button-label-text-color : #ff4081
}

rule is preceding the latter.
Just add an !important to the CSS rule, like so:
.mat-mdc-button.mat-accent{ 
    --mdc-text-button-label-text-color : #ff4081 !important;
}

and it should work.

For Material 2 you can use color attribute and routerLinkActive directive:
<a mat-button [color]="rla.isActive ? 'accent' : null" routerLink="/create" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
  New Post
</a>

However, for Material 3 there are new guidelines for applying color:

Theme color of the button. This API is supported in M2 themes only, it
has no effect in M3 themes.
For information on applying color variants in M3, see
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-component-color-variants.

